# Declaring a function number of times

Tags: c, function

I recently came across a C source where the function name was declared multiple times sometimes in the header file and sometimes in the C files. I know it is not wrong by declaring the functions numerous times but my question is why should we declare a function so many times?

Comment: Show the source, otherwise we're left to guess as to the intentions of the author.

Comment: @tbert I wish I could have. But its pretty huge. Its a normal declaration of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We shouldn't. Bad coding. All these declarations must matched, otherwise there's going to be a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Conceivably, some of the declarations might be inside conditional define blocks, and used under different circumstances:

```
#ifdef USE_ALT_FUNCS
  myfunc(type1 t);
#else
  myfunc(type2 t);
#endif
```

But this would be a maintenance headache so it's still not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but, maybe they declare the function many times because they use overload of operators, Polymorphism, or overload of methods.
I think that in your case is overload of methods or overload of operation.

Sorry for my English i think the correct name is "Function overloading".
I hope i could help you, but i think is better if you show us a example where we can see it.

Comment: The question is about C, not C++. There's no overloading in C.

Comment: ok, sorry but I thought it could help him. Should I delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is useful to redeclare (or redefine) a function because of some subtle side-effects. One example is shown [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Inline.html#Inline), in the last paragraph, concerning inlined functions.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a function returning a non-int value (e.g double), the calling function must know the return-type of the called function. Otherwise a return type of int is assumed but this could result in a possible loss of information (e.g double to int).

One way to prevent this loss of information is to explicitly declare the function in the calling routine.  This might explain why you noticed so many declarations of the same function.

Answer (score 0):

I have an instance where I am declaring the function first as a placeholder, and later with the accompanying code:

```
int mouse[2];
void doit();
void submouse(int btn, int state, int x, int y){
  mouse[0] = x;
  mouse[1] = y;
  doit();
}
void newwindow(){
  subWindow[1][0] = glutCreateSubWindow(mainWindow, 10, 10, 616, 274);
  windowlevel = 1;
  glutMouseFunc(submouse);
}
void doit(){
  // if subwindow has not been created, create subwindow
  if(windowlevel == 0)newwindow();
  else{ //process whatever the mouse clicked
  }
}
```

This has worked for the past year using gcc 4:4.8.2-4 on my AMD64 machine, but I get an error message on my i686 machine (Debian stable) using gcc 4:4.7.2-1:

> Blockquote

```
program.c:4418:6: error: static declaration of ‘doit’ follows non-static declaration
program.c:3745:6: note: previous declaration of ‘doit’ was here
```

doit() is declared as a placeholder because it is called by submouse().
submouse() is declared as associated with the subwindow that newwindow() creates.
The code for doit() is not included until after newwindow() is declared because doit() calls newwindow().
Note: doit() is a state function. After the subwindow has been constructed,it disappears until it is called by submouse().